# Is there a way to include 2 Angular Apps in SinglePage?

Tags: c#, angular, model-view-controller, single-page-application, angular-elements

I have a Multi-App structured Angular project within an Asp.Net MVC project. I need to include 2 Angular Apps in SinglePage. But Angular renders only the initial App tag. Can someone suggest a solution?

[image: Angular MVC file strucuture]

Comment: You will have to share the routing of sub-apps with main app. The steps involved are nicely documented here - https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: Another approach you could investigate is by using Angular elements, but I suspect it won't be possible to have routing in the individual applications (what would you see in the browser navigation bar when navigating?).

Comment: @ Amogh Sarpotdar   - Thanks for the article. It helped me.

Comment: @julianobrasil - Yes, i also implemented my requirement with angular elements in my main project and it is working fine.Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Good to know!!! I think one of the hugest things people are about to discover is Angular Elements. It's, by far, the easiest way to build up micro frontends. I don't think we have another framework that allows this kind of stuff with so tiny changes in your codebase.